# Importing first line of TXT files to a spreadsheet

Tags: csv, import, bulk

I have 2000 txt files that I need to read the first line of (it should contain a person's name).

Ideally I would have a spreadsheet/csv with

```
FILENAME, FIRST LINE OF FILE
```

Comment: What operating systems do you have available? I think something like this will be much easier on linux or OS X than windows.

Comment: I agree, a bash script could probably handle this quite nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Windows, you can do this with a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT=names.csv
del %OUTPUT% > nul 2>&1

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set /p NAME=< %%f
    echo %%f,!NAME! >> %OUTPUT%
)

endlocal
```

If you want the filename without the extension, change the for loop to this:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set /p NAME=< %%f
    set INPUT=%%f
    echo !INPUT:~0,-4!, !NAME! >> %OUTPUT%
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I came up with was

```
$ perl -e 'for(@ARGV){open($f,"<",$_);print"$_,",scalar<$f>}' *.txt
aaa.txt,aaa
bbb.txt,bbb
```

Perl works on Windows as well as Unix,Linux,etc - but you may need to install it first.